# datamaps.js - How to smoothly transition between bubble sizes?

Tags: d3.js, datamaps

I am using datamaps' bubbles to show data that changes slightly from year to year:

http://jsbin.com/goqeve/edit?html,output

(Click between the '1990' and '2000' buttons on the bottom)

When I replace the bubbles with `map.bubbles([...])`, the default animation is for new bubbles to grow from the center, which obscures the small changes in size. How can I get the bubbles to transition smoothly (i.e. grow or shrink) between sizes instead of replacing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the datamaps source I noticed it does a transition on the circles, but it uses ​`JSON.stringify`​ on the bubble object as the key for the selection. If any attribute changes it’s considered new data and has its initial radius set to 0. I added an option to only use the lat/lng as the key so I don’t need to re-write the transition: https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/pull/225

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have your bubble data in a list called `Nodes`.

When you transition from 1990 to 2000 (or vice-versa), you can update the radii of the data in `Nodes` and then redraw them by calling `map.bubbles(Nodes)`. I tried it and it smoothly transitioned into the new radius and not redrawing them.